# React, gatsbyjs: Looping through object - Component doesn't get rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I have the following component in a Gatsbyjs project:

```
styleItem.js

import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image'
import {StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import {Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

import '../styles/styles.css'

const StyleItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <StaticQuery 
            query={graphql`
                query {
                    street: file(relativePath: { eq: "2.jpg" }) {
                        childImageSharp {
                        fluid(quality: 90, maxWidth: 1920) {
                            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    casual: file(relativePath: { eq: "3.jpg" }) {
                        childImageSharp {
                        fluid(quality: 90, maxWidth: 1920) {
                            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    athletic: file(relativePath: { eq: "3.jpg" }) {
                        childImageSharp {
                        fluid(quality: 90, maxWidth: 1920) {
                            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            `}

            render={data => { Object.keys(data).map((image, i ) => {

                    console.log(props.stylesItem[image].name)
                    console.log(image)
                    return (
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <div class="style-box">
                                <StyledBackgroundImage
                                    Tag="div"
                                    className="style-box-img"
                                    fluid={data[image].childImageSharp.fluid}
                                >
                                </StyledBackgroundImage>
                                <div class="style-text-box">
                                    <h5 class="h5">{props.stylesItem[image].style}</h5>
                                    <h3 class="h3 style-description">{props.stylesItem[image].name}</h3>
                                    <div class="extra-style-details">
                                        <p class="style-short-desc">{props.stylesItem[image].tagline}</p>
                                        <p>{props.stylesItem[image].text}</p>
                                        <ul class="hashtag-list">
                                            <li class="style-attribut"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                        )
                    })
                }
            }
        />
    )
}

export default StyleItem

const StyledBackgroundImage = styled(BackgroundImage)`
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
`
```

I'm passing in the following props to this component (abc dummy strings for better readability):

```
    stylesItem: {
            street: {
                style: "// STREET",
                name: "THE CANVAS",
                tagline: "abc",
                text: "abc",
                hashtags: [
                    "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"
                ]
            },
            casual: {
                style: "// CASUAL",
                name: "THE CLASSIC",
                tagline: "abc",
                text: "abc",
                hashtags: [
                    "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"
                ]
            },
            athletic: {
                style: "// ATHLETIC",
                name: "THE PERFORMER",
                tagline: "abc",
                text: "abc",
                hashtags: [
                    "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"
                ]
            }
        }
```

I'm using Gatsby's Staticquery to load in 3 images (street, casual, athletic) and want to render the part in the second return statement 3 times (1 for each image), each time with the background image loading in dynamically as well as the content.

The 2 console.log() statements print out as expected.

```
console.log(props.stylesItem[image].name)
console.log(image)

THE CANVAS
street
THE CLASSIC
casual
THE PERFORMER
athletic
```

However nothing gets rendered to the screen and I'm not seeing any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your render prop on `StaticQuery` doesn't return anything, and therefore doesn't render anything.

In the `StaticQuery` render prop you are mapping over the keys of the queried data, then generating a bunch of JSX successfully. But notice you are not actually doing anything with it because the resulting JSX doesn't get returned.

So the entire `StyleItem` component does a bunch of work and then doesn't render anything, because the only thing it renders is `StaticQuery`.

```
const StyleItem = ({ stylesItem }) => {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query {
          street: file(relativePath: { eq: "1.png" }) {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(quality: 90, maxWidth: 1920) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
              }
            }
          }
          casual: file(relativePath: { eq: "2.png" }) {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(quality: 90, maxWidth: 1920) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
              }
            }
          }
          athletic: file(relativePath: { eq: "3.png" }) {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(quality: 90, maxWidth: 1920) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={data => {
        // Make sure to return something here
        return Object.keys(data).map(imageTitle => {
          const fluidProp = data[imageTitle].childImageSharp.fluid
          const imageData = stylesItem[imageTitle]
          return (
            <>
              <StyledBackgroundImage
                Tag="div"
                className="style-box-img"
                fluid={fluidProp}
              ></StyledBackgroundImage>
              <div>
                <h5>{imageData.style}</h5>
                <h3>{imageData.name}</h3>
                <p>{imageData.tagline}</p>
                <p>{imageData.text}</p>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        })
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

---

Something worth nothing with [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is that

> when the only statement in an arrow function is `return`, we can remove `return` and remove the surrounding curly brackets

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression  
// equivalent to: => { return expression; }
```

So the above render prop on `StaticQuery` could be further simplified as:

```
render={data =>
  Object.keys(data).map(imageTitle => {...})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, adding the return statement explicitly before "Object.keys(data)..." worked. Out of curiosity: From my understanding I used the arrow function in my code? Or did I miss something here?

Comment: Yes, you used an arrow function in the render prop, and it had curly braces so the explicit return keyword was required. So the two solutions were to either add the return statement before the curly braces or remove the curly braces.